# How can I get the total lines of code for a TFS collection?

Tags: tfs

What's the best way to figure out the total lines of code in a TFS Collection? Do I need to use the SDK in some way to do this? Or is there a reporting tool?

Comment: Curious: why do you care about lines of code in the collection? How do you define "code"? How do you define "lines"?

Comment: I'm trying to price out some solutions for searching code in TFS, and many of the companies with solutions provide pricing by the lines of code.

Comment: Even more curious: I've never needed such a global code search feature. What do you need it for? Will it be smart enough to only look at the most recent source code?

Comment: It would only look at most recent source code with the ability to search history if needed. We house database objects in our TFS as well, so this would encompass all code, database or C#/VB code we have.

Comment: SSIS packages? Other artifacts which are not "code"? Like UML models?

Comment: Whatever is checked into TFS. Or at least... anything that is viewable in TFS. I'm not sure about those, I would assume it wouldn't allow you to search those.

Comment: "viewable"? Just be careful with that definition. There's all sorts of things you can check into TFS. Not all of it is "code", and not all of the "code" has "lines".

Comment: Is this a line of code? `}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way, but you almost certainly have to Get the source code into a workspace and then run the tool of your choice to count "lines" (depending on what you consider to be a "line of code").

There are no end of tools to count lines in source files, and it's trivial to write one yourself, so I won't try to go into detail of that part of the problem.

So the other part is to either manually Get the source code to your PC, or use [tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to automate the Get process from a batch file or similar. The tricky bit is figuring out the rather unfriendly tf command line, but this is a pretty easy task to achieve if youjust read through the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that I'm at a loss trying to find a good reason for it, but if you get the entire collection, you can then count the number of lines in every file that is of a type that has code in it (*.cs, vb, aspx, etc.)

Many tools can count lines, but if you need to roll your own, you could try counting the occurrences of a regex like ".+\n".

Answer (score -1):

I had written this many years ago. It can work on local folders though, so if you have a local copy of the TFS code, it can still work. Not the best quality code, but just a quick and dirty way to get a report in the grid that you can copy to Excel (again, not the best automation, but gets the job done)-

[Add a few controls that are needed in the forms app]

```
    private static int totalLinesCount = 0;
    private static int totalLinesOfCode = 0;
    private static int totalComments = 0;

    private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            totalLinesCount = 0;
            totalLinesOfCode = 0;
            totalComments = 0;
            lblTotalCount.Text = "";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtFileName.Text);
            if (di.Exists)
            {
                FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFiles(txtSearchPattern.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                rtbReport.Text = "";
                Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("Report");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("TotalCount", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Commented", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Summary", typeof(string));
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
                {
                    if (fi.Exists)
                    {
                        int fileLinesCount = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName).Length;
                        int commentedCode = 0;

                        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fi.FullName))
                        {
                            if (line.TrimStart().StartsWith("/") || (line.TrimStart().StartsWith("*")))
                            {
                                commentedCode++;
                            }
                        }

                        rtbReport.Text += string.Format("{0}: {1}; Actual Code: {2}; Commented lines: {3};{4}",
                            fi.Name, fileLinesCount.ToString(), fileLinesCount - commentedCode, commentedCode,"\n");
                        totalLinesCount += fileLinesCount;
                        totalComments += commentedCode;

                        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                        dr["FileName"] = fi.Name;
                        dr["TotalCount"] = fileLinesCount;
                        dr["Code"] = fileLinesCount - commentedCode;
                        dr["Commented"] = commentedCode;
                        dr["Summary"] = string.Format("Code: {0}, Commented: {1}, Total: {2}",
                            fileLinesCount-commentedCode, commentedCode, fileLinesCount);

                        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
                    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                }

                totalLinesOfCode = totalLinesCount - totalComments;

                lblTotalCount.Text = string.Format("{0}: {1}; Code: {2}; Comments: {3}",
                    "Total Number of lines in all files", totalLinesCount.ToString(),
                    totalLinesOfCode.ToString(), totalComments.ToString());
                rtbReport.Text += lblTotalCount.Text;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Folder does not exist. Select a valid folder",
                    "Folder not found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking how to count lines of code in a file on disk. He wanted to know about lines of code in TFS, which might well not have involved counting lines - TFS keeps track of some of these things. Also, showing `ex.Message` is only adequate to inform users of a problem - it's not enough to inform a developer. Use `ex.ToString()` for that.